# How to make curried merge sort properly generic

Tags: scala

In [Scala by Example](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaByExample.pdf), there is an implementation of merge sort that takes a comparison function to use internally:

```
def mergeSort[T <% Ordered[T]](less: (T, T) => Boolean)(list: List[T]): List[T] = {

  def merge(xs: List[T], ys: List[T]): List[T] = {
    if (xs.isEmpty) ys
    else if (ys.isEmpty) xs
    else if (less(xs.head, ys.head)) xs.head :: merge(xs.tail, ys)
    else ys.head :: merge(ys.tail, xs)
  }

  val n = list.length / 2
  if (n == 0) list
  else merge(mergeSort(less)(list.take(n)), mergeSort(less)(list.drop(n)))
}
```

I can call this as shown in the book:

```
mergeSort((x: Int, y: Int) => x < y)(List(3,2,1))
```

Cool. But what I'd like is this:

```
def orderedLess[T <% Ordered[T]](x: T, y: T) = x < y
def basicMergeSort = mergeSort(orderedLess)_
```

The compiler doesn't like that.

```
Lists.scala:62: error: No implicit view available from T => Ordered[T].
  def basicMergeSort = mergeSort(orderedLess)_
                                 ^
Lists.scala:62: error: No implicit view available from Any => Ordered[Any].
  def basicMergeSort = mergeSort(orderedLess)_
                                ^
```

The way to solve this problem seems to be to throw a type parameter in there. Either

```
def basicMergeSort = mergeSort[Int](orderedLess)_
```

or

```
def basicMergeSort = mergeSort(orderedLess[Int])_
```

will compile, but I want to be able to pass it any kind of Ordered type. What am I doing wrong? I'm new to Scala, so I could be totally misunderstanding something, but I'm not really grokking those errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off:

You will never see something like `[T <% Ordered[T]]` together with `(less: (T, T) => Boolean)`.
Either you want the user to specify a comparison function or you want an implicit Ordering so you can access a default comparison function. You can see this in the std library.

```
 def sortWith(lt: (A, A) => Boolean): List[A] 
 def sorted[B >: A](implicit ord: math.Ordering[B]): List[A]
```

So I would leave the signature like it is from your link.

`def mergeSort[T](less: (T, T) => Boolean)(list: List[T]): List[T]`

Now back to the question.

**Solution 1**

This is similar to your approach. The compiler seems to need additional information regarding the type.

```
def orderedLess[T <% Ordered[T]](x: T, y: T) = x < y
def basicMergeSort[T <% Ordered[T]] = mergeSort[T](orderedLess)_
```

You can also merge it like this:

```
def basicMergeSort[T <% Ordered[T]] = mergeSort((x: T, y: T) => x < y) _
```

The "bad" stuff comes when calling it however. It only works like that.

```
basicMergeSort[Char].apply(List('a','d','c'))
```

The compiler won't infer the type for you and you can not use the sugar syntax for the `apply`.
`def basicMergeSort[T <% Ordered[T]]` will be translated to something like `def basicMergeSort[T](implicit ord: T => Ordered[T])` and when trying to call `basicMergeSort[Char](List('a','d','c'))` it will treat the list as the implicit parameter, which of course does not work out.

**Solution 2**

This is a solution without currying. It is basically a method that only accepts lists with elements that have an implicit ordering and uses `mergeSort` with the desired function.

```
def basicMergeSort[T <% Ordered[T]](list: List[T]) = mergeSort((x: T, y: T) => x < y)(list)
```

Here everything is inferred and nice.

```
basicMergeSort(List('a','d','c'))
```

**Final words**

I'm not really happy that I couldn't find a nice way with currying. Maybe someone with more insight can provide a better answer.

Comment: Thanks for this! Your first point makes a lot of sense to me, so I learned something here even if it wasn't what I meant to :) Solution 2 does do what I wanted without any terrible shortcomings, but I agree, I'd like to see how currying ought to work here.